# Powershell: Return the second line of a Search only

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to return the result of the second line of a search I'm performing on a txt file.
the data is in the format of

```
Readings       : \\Server1\memory\available mbytes :
                 2107
```

I want to get 2107 only.
This is what I have so far:

```
$file = "D:\PerfTest.txt" # import data
$data = gc $file
$RAM = $Data | Select-String -Pattern "available mbytes :" | ForEach-Object -Context 1
```

but it gives me the following:

```
Readings       : \\Server1\memory\available mbytes :
                  2107
```

But I want to get the figure only. Any help please?

thanks

Just to add to the above, if I use

```
$RAM = $Data | Select-String -Pattern "available mbytes :" -Context 1 | Foreach {if ($_ -match '(\d+)$') {$matches[1]}}
```

it returns whole numbers and not decimals. so anything with a decimal come out 78125 instead of 0.78125

Comment: `$Data | Select-String -Pattern "available mbytes :" -Context 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.Context.PostContext[0].Trim()}`

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194543/powershell-return-the-second-line-of-a-search-only#comment54196379_33194543), `-Context` should be an argument to `Select-String`, not `ForEach-Object`.

The `-Context` parameter takes one or two integers to indicate how many lines before and after each match you want included.

In your case, you want 0 lines before and 1 line after, so the argument should be `0,1`. Instead of loading the entire file into a variable, I would probably point `Select-String` directly to the file instead:

```
$RAM = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern "available mbytes :" -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object {
    +$_.Context.PostContext[0].Trim()
}
```

The `+` will ensure that `$RAM` is an integer and not a string

Comment: use `$_.line` if you also want the line contening the pattern